# Sensitivity Testing - Using Probit GLM to Infer Parameters of the Independent Variable

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, probit, sensitivity-specificity

I am an engineer working with some sensitivity data.  In this type of experiment, you test a device at a certain stimulus and observe whether or not it fails (binary outcome).  For example, you might drop some parts from different heights and observe what heights cause the part to break.  Because the strength of the part has some variability, there will be some heights that cause some parts to break but others survive from that same height.

What I care about understanding is the distribution of failure strength of my part.  I can assume that this distribution is normal from domain knowledge and previous work.  I have seen others solve this problem using a GLM with probit link function as follows.  Assume that 1 means "part broke under this stimulus" and 0 means "part survived the stimulus".

```
#data 

x <- c(rep(666, 4), rep(492, 4), rep(572, 4), rep(537, 4), rep(597, 4), rep(555, 4), rep(578, 4), rep(548, 4), rep(591, 4), rep(606, 4), rep(534, 4))
 
y <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)

xglm <- glm(y~x, family = binomial(link = probit))

ab <-  as.vector(xglm$coef)
muhat <- -ab[1]/ab[2]
sighat <- 1/ab[2]

muhat
sighat
```

I see that this works (by comparing to results from commercial software) but don't know why and I can't find these formulas in any google searches.  Why is -1 * (intercept / coefficient of x) equal to the mean of the distribution of the stimulus values that caused failure?  Why is the standard deviation equal to 1 / (coefficient of x)?  Are there any references that can provide some intuition behind this?

For background: I am not a trained statistician but do my best to try to understand moderately complex methods.  This is confusing to me because I have never used regression to understand things about the distribution of one of the independent variables...it's usually to view the coefficient of the variable.

Thank you!

Edit:  after reviewing the first comment, I edited the question to clarify that it's not the distribution of heights that caused failure that I am interested in. This means the whole title of my post is sort of mis-specified and i may have to delete and re-post under a better title. It's the distribution of "failure strength" of the part.  For example, I could drop the part from a height of 10000 and it would break, but that same part would have also broke at maybe 600.  So we can't just average the heights that caused failure to find the mean failure strength of of the part.  Just by typing this, I'm connecting some dots in my head and thinking maybe this is a latent variable problem, which I know probit regression has been used for.

Comment: I can't replicate your claims with your code.  From your code, `muhat=574.6419` but `mean(x[y==1])=601.35`.

Comment: You’re asking a lot of questions. That’s fine, but it can discourage people from posting answers if they only have a response to one question. It might be better to ask several questions here once your sort out the issues with the code not giving Demetri the results you got. (Addressing your question about confidence intervals for percentiles, that was the example given the first time I saw how bootstrap works.)

Comment: @DemetriPananos  I misspoke slightly but critically - I apologize..  What I the code is finding is not the mean of the stimulus values that caused failure , but the mean and sd of the failure strength distribution of the part.  We could test the part at 10,000 and it would obviously cause failure, driving mean(x[y==1]) WAY up, but it doesn't change anything about the underlying mean and sd of the strength distribution of the part because the part would have failed at a value much less than that.    I will edit the question to clarify and also remove the 2nd question about CI's on percentiles